# Photoshop - is there a way to link images accross multiple psd files?

Tags: image, web, photoshop

With Photoshop I have multiple web banners at different sizes that contain the same image. Is there a way to change the image on one psd file so that it will automatically change on all the other psd files?

I'm using Creative Cloud

Any help will be really appreciated

Thanks

Comment: I'm happy to be told if I am wrong, but I think most folks have a single large master image and then generate smaller versions of it automagically using scripting or actions.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create the banner in the biggest size
2. Right click the layer and choose Convert to smart object
3. Create a new document with next banner measurements. Go back to the already created banner and use the move tool (v) and drag the layer/layers in to the new document.
4. If you now doubleclick your smart object (doesnt matter in which document) you will open a new document. If you make any changes there it will be changed in both banners.

You can choose more than one layer to become a smart object together. When you double click the smart object you will find all your layers separate but in the banner document it will only show as one file.

This is what the symbol on a smart layer looks like

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use linked smart objects.
If you have photoshop CC you can [follow this](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/how-to/photoshop-linked-smart-objects.html) for instruction on how you'd do it.

(Sorry for the link only answer but it's a video and will make more sense then listing the steps)

Answer (score 0):

if you use Photoshop CC 2014 or 2015 you can place images as linked files, same way as InDesign or HTML docs. Adobe gives now two choices Place Embeded or Place Linked.